# What does this code do? Memory-allocation

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

Can someone help me get a better understand on how memory-allocation works like? I would appreciate if someone could go through step by step (hopefully with pictures) what happens in this code:

```
char a[3][4] = {"xy", "abcd", "!?"};
char (*b)[4], *c;
b = a + 1;
c = *a + 1;
```

I looked around but found nothing explaining this thoroughly, thanks!

Edit:
I would be grateful if someone could explain it using memoryblocks, ex, [x][y][][a][b][c][d][]

Comment: It can be considered to not do anything, since it has no side-effects ...

Comment: Shall the oversized string "abcd", *five* chars in length including the terminator, stuffed into an undersized *four*-char array be accounted for in whatever answers are provided?

Comment: @WhozCraig Nope, that's not a problem. `char foo[3] = "foo";` is well-defined and there is no terminator added if the literal is exactly the length of the array.

Comment: @unwind A C thing? C++ will puke on this. Egads.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, standard C.

Comment: @unwind Thanks very much for the info. Yuck. Like *that* isn't a terminator-search overreach just waiting in the wings.

Comment: @WhozCraig It's pretty awesome, for instance when you have a fixed-length string-like value which doesn't need a terminator (like the `"\x7fELF"` ELF magic identifier, and so on).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char a[3][4] = {"xy", "abcd", "!?"};
```

The first command allocates a 3 by 4 matrix on the stack and initializes the elements of the 2-dimensional array with some chars.

```
char (*b)[4], *c;
```

Reserves a pointer to character array sized 4 named b on the stack. Additionally it creates a second char pointer named c.

```
b = a + 1;
```

You store in the pointer b the starting address of the array a + 1 that means the address of the second element (second row of 4 characters).

```
c = *a + 1;
```

You dereference a, producing the pointer to first element of a (an element of a is a char array of size 4), and add 1 to that pointer - thats the second letter of the first entry.

Comment: *Reserves a char pointer named b on the stack 4 elements with 4 elements*: What does it mean?

Comment: `b` is really a "pointer to array of 4 characters". I am not 100% positive, but I think that sizeof(*b) would be 4, not 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // the second dimension should 5
  // since "abcd" is 4 chars + null terminator
  char a[3][5] = {"xy", "abcd", "!?"};
  char (*b)[5], *c;
  b = a + 1;
  c = *a + 1;

  // b = a + 1, thus it points to the second entry of a array
  printf("%s\n", b[0]);

  // c = *a + 1, thus it points where a points to, plus one,
  // thus in the second letter of a's first entry
  printf("%c\n", *c);
  return 0;
}
```

EDIT about your edit

```
a -> [x][y][0][0][0][a][b][c][d][0][!][?][0][0][0]
b -> [a][b][c][d][0][!][?][0][0][0]
c -> [y]
```

With zeroes I represent the null terminator. Notice that in your example, it's not vital to have one, but I think that is always a good thing to have null terminated strings in C. That's why I changed your code a bit.

Why not only 1 null terminator per string in `a`? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201116/2411320) answer.

Comment: The null terminatiors aren't they just supposed to be just 1, after. Ex: [x][y][\0][][][a]..

Comment: No. @Fjondor, since you are using an initializer list there, all the empty cells are going to be zero initialized.

Comment: @Fjondor I included a link which might help. Did the bracket explanation help?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `a` is an array of arrays of `char`. The variable `b` is a pointer to an array of `char`, `c` is a pointer to `char.

The variable `a` is initialized at declaration. The variable `b` is then assigned to point to the *second* array of `a` (i.e. `a[1]`), and `c` is assigned to the second letter of `a[0]`.

As for the assignment of `b`, the expressions `a[1]` and `*(a + 1)` are equivalent.

For the assignment of `c`, `a` by itself is a pointer to the first element of the array, i.e. it's a pointer `a[0]` (`a` is the same as `&a[0]`). By dereferencing `a` you get the first entry of `a`, that is you get `a[0]`. Adding one to `a[0]` give you the second character of `a[0]`, i.e. `a[0][1]`.